# Resume: How to create a textbox?

Tags: boxes, resume

I am creating a resume template. The picture below looks bad, is there a way to fit the entire bullet point "subject" into a box, so it is properly aligned ? Or is there a better solutions that you would suggest?

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article} 

%\usepackage{setspace}
%\singlespacing

\oddsidemargin=0.0in 
\evensidemargin=0.0in 
\textwidth=6.5in 
\marginparwidth=0.5in
\headheight=0pt 
\headsep=0pt 
\textheight=9.0in 
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\begin{document}
\centerline{\huge \bf My Name}
\vspace{2.5pt}
\centerline{$\bullet$ Naitonality $\bullet$ (Country code)phone number}
\centerline{Email}
\noindent{\LARGE \bf Education} \\
{\line(1,0){475}}
\noindent{\textbf{School} \hfill{Time}} \\
\hspace{10in}{Sixth Form } \hfill{Time}\par
\noindent{\hspace{0.4in} $\bullet$ Subjects: physics, biology, chemistry, japanese, english, mathematics, history, geography, design and technology, religous studies}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: yes, but i dont really like it, thats why i want to create my own .

Comment: If I use `tabular`, the line become go over the right hand side of the page. Is there a way to specify the size of the table ?

Comment: That's what the `p{<width>}` specification does.  There are many different types of table, however....

Comment: i used p{0.75\textwidth} , it still doesnt achieve what I want

Comment: As a sidenote, I would instead use the `description` environment for this sort of thing (at least, this is what I did with mine).

Answer (score 1):

One try with `enumitem`:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

%\usepackage{setspace}
%\singlespacing

\oddsidemargin=0.0in
\evensidemargin=0.0in
\textwidth=6.5in
\marginparwidth=0.5in
\headheight=0pt
\headsep=0pt
\textheight=9.0in
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\begin{document}
\centerline{\huge \bf My Name}
\vspace{2.5pt}
\centerline{$\bullet$ Naitonality $\bullet$ (Country code)phone number}
\centerline{Email}
\noindent{\LARGE \bf Education} \\
{\line(1,0){475}}
\noindent{\textbf{School} \hfill{Time}} \\
\hspace{10in}{Sixth Form } \hfill{Time}\par
\begin{description}[labelindent=.4in,style=multiline,leftmargin=1.3in]
 \item[$\bullet$ Subjects:] physics, biology, chemistry, japanese, english, mathematics, history, geography, design and technology, religous studies
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Change `leftmargin=1.3in` as per your wish.

Another try with `parbox`. Put `\usepackage{linegoal}` in preamble and

```
\noindent\hspace*{0.4in} $\bullet$ Subjects: 
 \parbox[t]{\linegoal}{physics, biology, chemistry, japanese, english, mathematics, history, geography, design and technology, religous studies}
```

will produce

[image]

Comment: I prefer the second option, but i still dont want the word "design" to appear at the end of the first line, it would be better if you can make it appear on the second line, such that it will intersect with the right column, which contains "time". Hope you can understand what I am trying to say. Thanks

Comment: @asd: `it will intersect with the right column,`? Sorry I didn't follow.

Comment: i m very sorry, I mean it will *not* intersect with the right column. What I want is to set the dimension of `parbox[t]{\linegoal}`

Comment: I just found   a way to get around this by doing `\parbox[t]{0.75\linegoal}`

Comment: @asd Things like that are possible, provided we know what exactly is the need ;)

Comment: sorry mate, i should have given u an image, but i really didnt have one at that time.